# можно ли открыть гугл форму из гугл таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-forms

озадачился вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на ячейку в столбце `заявка в автоотдел`, открывалась гугл форма (шаблонная) под номером который был в той ячейке на которую нажали? заранее благодарю за внимание =)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы не вставить в эту ячейку гиперссылку на нужную форму заявки? Стандартное средство, как-никак.

Comment: Если для "номера 5" сделать заполняемое поле, а в URL указать его значение, то при открытии формы оно будет им заполнено. То есть покажет "номер 5".